# Preventing children (span) from overflowing in middle of word/line (CSS/HTML)

Tags: css, overflow, parent-child, html

So I have several spans inside of a div as so:

```
<div id="parent">
  <span class="child">span one</span>
  <span class="child">span two</span>
  <span class="child">span three</span>
  <span class="child">span four</span>
  <span class="child">span five</span>
</div>
```

parent div(#parent) is fixed width, not fluid. span.child has an auto width, with a padding of 3px on either side. I am having an issue where the span tag will overflow to the next line of #parent, even in the middle of a sentence.

For example: span.child containing "span four" is at the end of the first line in #parent, it will overflow the word "four" to the next line, with "span" being on the line above still. I have tried word-wrap to no avail.

Any ideas where I should start for this? I'm not sure if I need to apply styling to the span, or the parent div. And which property is best for this, I've only come up with word-wrap and can't get that work. Thanks!

Comment: `display: block;`? Let's see your CSS.

Comment: @MattKieran thanks! I ALWAYS forget about the usefulness of display:block. I applied display:block and then a float:left to it. Perfect.

Answer (score 2):

To prevent division of an element into two lines, set `white-space: nowrap` on it. It seems that this, preventing normal line wrapping inside `span` elements, is what you are looking for, rather than preventing overflow (which would be a different matter).

If the content of some of the `span` elements does not fit onto a line inside the `div` element, even when standing there alone, *then* you have an overflow issue. The default is visible overflow.